# Powershell Query - Columns are missing While selecting Items from List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, caml-query

I am trying to get records from Office 365 SharePoint list using Powershell Script, through "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery" query. It fetches all the items and the values. However, there are certain columns that is not available in the list item object returned by the query.

Why are few columns in a Sharepoint list not available through Powershell scripts? Is there some means by which SharePoint disallows the access to certain columns in a list from Powershell query?

My Code is here:

```
$qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
$items = $list.GetItems($qry)
$Context.Load($items)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Any support would be highly appreciated.